# Hyper-V within Azure virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v, azure

I'm trying to move my development and testing environment in the Azure cloud.

I would like to know if it's possible to have an Hyper-V running within an Azure virtual machine ?

For the moment I haven't found anything about that excepted using VirtualBox as the Azure virtual machine is itself a virtual machine and Hyper-V or VmWare don't like it.

Google didn't help me to find how to enable Hyper-V within an Azure virtual machine, any clues ?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to install Hyper-V in azure VMs, because as you may have been noticed, those VMs are already hosted on Hyper-V.

Therefore, may you please describe how you would use the hypervisor in your azure VM and maybe we may si if you really need to do so, maybe you should consider an alternative and I would suggest you VMware or VirtualBox.

Answer (score 1):

Nested virtualization is now possible.

Nested virtualization is a feature that allows you to run Hyper-V inside of a Hyper-V virtual machine. In other words, with nested virtualization, a Hyper-V host itself can be virtualized.

See this link for improtant prerequisites.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyperv_on_windows/user_guide/nesting?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396